# return String imageData to image on my jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

i am getting a imageData value like,

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAASwAAACWCAYAAABkW7XSAAACB0lEQVR4nO3UMQ0AMAzAsPKHUpIbhX1TJB/   +c2V29wAUzO8AgFeGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZhgVkGBaQYVhAhmEBGYYFZBgWkGFYQIZhARmGBWQYFpBhWECGYQEZF7C8Z2zone7OAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

how to we get this image String value to Image and set it in  HttpServletResponse response and get it on jsp like...

```
   <div>
      <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/profilepic.jsp" 
    width="200" height="200">
   </div>
```

and controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/profilepic", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void profilePIC(HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    response.setContentType("image/png");
             String imageData = //get image String value
             OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();

    //here i wan to return image on my jsp !!
    }
```

i want to show my that image on jsp. but how ? Thanks..

Comment: It mentions base64. Did you check what that is?

Comment: i already tried `byte[] byteImage = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(imageData.substring(imageData.indexOf(",") + 1));` for get byte[] it convert as byte[] but not shown on page.

Comment: `DatatypeConverter` is part of `java.xml.bind`, I would recommend using [`Base64.getDecoder().decode(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#decode-java.lang.String-). But I suspect it would work with even your approach. Compare the resulting bytes to the original image!

Comment: Thanks for queck reply, i just get this data when add user and get it on redirected page without save on HD. where i get the image value like given in Question.